# Pass argument to angular hammer function besides event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arguments, hammer.js, pan

I want to call a function on a hammer pan and I want to pass a custom value/argument with it.

`<div hm-panmove="startPan('customString')"></div>`

I thought I could use something like this:

```
$scope.startPan = function (event, string) {
//... handler
}
```

But unfortunately this does not work.

Link to angular hammer:
http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/

Is there a possibility to do something like this?

Any hints appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late, but I faced a similar requirement. Answering in case others find it useful.
The angular hammer allows the attribute values to be angular expressions. So your approach was in the right direction. If your handler needs access to the event, then use $event as the parameter. So your html would look like:

```
<div hm-panmove="startPan($event, 'customString')"></div>
```

Comment: I did not test this, as I'm not working on that project anymore. So I cannot say that is the solution, but it seems legitimate :)